# Python allow accepting two strings depends on cases

Tags: python, string, openpyxl, uppercase, lowercase

I found the error when I read excel using openpyxl library that the library reads `'[Content_Types].xml'` while all my .xlsx files to read contains `'[content_types].xml'`.

The library calls the file by string `ARC_CONTENT_TYPES = '[Content_Types].xml'` and read the file by

```
def read_manifest(self):
    src = self.archive.read(ARC_CONTENT_TYPES)
    root = fromstring(src)
    self.package = Manifest.from_tree(root)
```

I would like to change it to accept both `'[Content_Types].xml'` and `'[content_types].xml'` so that the library can accept both cases.

Will there be any helpful tips or any other methods to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost a year ago and I forgot to put how I managed it. I basically fixed the related python library so that it can accept both cases by putting 'if ... else ...' condition into the library.

```
if xmlstring.startswith('c'):
    ARC_CONTENT_TYPES = '[content_Types].xml'
else:
    ARC_CONTENT_TYPES = '[Content_Types].xml'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).